# MongoDB return two object for every group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get two objects $first and $last after grouping. Is it possible?

Something like this, but this is not working:

```js
{ "$group": {
  "_id": "type",
  "values": [{
        "time": { "$first": "$time" },
        "value": { "$first": "$value" }
        }, 
        {
          "time": { "$last": "$time" },
          "value": { "$last": "$value" }
        }]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) values from an array with the aggregation framework, you need to use [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) first to "de-normalize" the array as individual documents. There is also another trick to put those back in an array.

Assuming a document like this

```js
{
    "type": "abc",
    "values": [
        { "time": ISODate("2014-06-12T22:35:42.260Z"), "value": "ZZZ" },
        { "time": ISODate("2014-06-12T22:36:45.921Z"), "value": "KKK" },
        { "time": ISODate("2014-06-12T22:37:18.237Z"), "value": "AAA" } 
    ]
}
```

And assuming that your array is already sorted your would do:

If you do not care about the results being in an array just [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```js
db.junk.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$values" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$type",
        "ftime":  { "$first": "$values.time" },
        "fvalue": { "$first": "$values.value" },
        "ltime":  { "$last": "$values.time" },
        "lvalue": { "$last": "$values.value" },
    }}
])
```

For those results in array then there is a trick to it:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$values" },
    { "$project": {
        "type": 1,
        "values": 1,
        "indicator": { "$literal": ["first", "last"] }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$type",
        "ftime":  { "$first": "$values.time" },
        "fvalue": { "$first": "$values.value" },
        "ltime":  { "$last": "$values.time" },
        "lvalue": { "$last": "$values.value" },
        "indicator": { "$first": "$indicator" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$indicator" },
    { "$project": {
        "values": {
            "time": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$indicator", "first" ] },
                    "$ftime",
                    "$ltime"
                ]
            },
            "value": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$indicator", "first" ] },
                    "$fvalue",
                    "$lvalue"
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "values": { "$push": "$values" }
    }}
])
```

If your array is not sorted place an additional [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) stage before the very first [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to make sure your items are in the order you want them to be evaluated by [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/). A logical order where is by the "time" field, so:

```js
{ "$sort": { "type": 1, "values.time": 1 } }
```

The [**`$literal`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) declares an array to identify the values of "first" and "last" which are later "unwound" to create two copies of each grouped document. These are then evaluated using the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to re-assign to a single field for "values" which is finally push back into an array using [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).

Remember to allways try to [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) first in the pipeline in order to reduce the number of documents you are working on to what you reasonable want. You pretty much never want to do this over whole collections, especially when you are using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on arrays.

---

Just as a final note [**`$literal`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) is introduced/exposed in MongoDB 2.6 and greater versions. For prior versions you can interchange that with the undocumented **`$const`**.